# How to add Edit | Delete button on rows?

Tags: plugins, database, columns

I want to render columns with actions.

When hover on row, `Edit | Delete` links show.

Problem at function `column_name($item)`.

I don't know why don't run to this function.

I tried to add `wp_die()` into this function but don't have anything change.

I written class extend `WP_List_Table`:

```
class Custom_Table_Example_List_Table extends WP_List_Table
{
    function __construct()
    {
        global $status, $page;

        parent::__construct(array(
            'singular' => 'dathangnhanh',
            'plural' => 'dathangnhanhs',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * [OPTIONAL] this is example, how to render column with actions,
     * when you hover row "Edit | Delete" links showed
     *
     * @param $item - row (key, value array)
     * @return HTML
     */
    function column_name($item)
    {
        // links going to /admin.php?page=[your_plugin_page][&other_params]
        // notice how we used $_REQUEST['page'], so action will be done on curren page
        // also notice how we use $this->_args['singular'] so in this example it will
        // be something like &dathangnhanh=2
        $actions = array(
            'edit' => sprintf('<a href="?page=persons_form&id=%s">%s</a>', $item['id'], __('Edit', 'cltd_example')),
            'delete' => sprintf('<a href="?page=%s&action=delete&id=%s">%s</a>', $_REQUEST['page'], $item['id'], __('Delete', 'cltd_example')),
        );
        return sprintf('%s %s',
            $item['madonhang'],
            $this->row_actions($actions)
        );
    }

    /**
     * [REQUIRED] This method return columns to display in table
     * you can skip columns that you do not want to show
     * like content, or description
     *
     * @return array
     */
    function get_columns()
    {
        $columns = array(
            'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />', //Render a checkbox instead of text
            'id' => __('STT', 'cltd_example'),
            'madonhang' => __('Mã Đơn Hàng', 'cltd_example'),
            'hoten' => __('Họ Tên', 'cltd_example'),
            'sdt' => __('Số Điện Thoại', 'cltd_example'),
            'email' => __('Email', 'cltd_example'),
            'tensp' => __('Tên Sản Phẩm', 'cltd_example'),
            'diachinhan' => __('Địa Chỉ Nhận', 'cltd_example'),
            'soluong' => __('Số Lượng', 'cltd_example'),
            'thanhtien' => __('Thành Tiền', 'cltd_example'),

        );
        return $columns;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code, you don't have a column called 'name'. Method column_name will display column content for the column 'name'. So, for instance, you have the column called 'madonhang'. Method for that column will be called 'column_madonhang'. Each column has own method with the similar name.

Comment: you save my life. I have too much time for this problem.